# Node.js and Gulp assistance

Tags: node.js, gulp

Good day, I’m new to Gulp and Node Js, I’ve been getting this error (shown below), I’ve done some research and I’ve not found any fixes.

```
 [Browserslist] Could not parse /Users/gendyblackman/Sites/blackmanimages/package.json. Ignoring it.
```

assert.js:269
    throw err;

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: clean

```
at getFunction (/Users/gendyblackman/Sites/blackmanimages/node_modules/undertaker/lib/helpers/normalizeArgs.js:15:5)
at map (/Users/gendyblackman/Sites/blackmanimages/node_modules/arr-map/index.js:20:14)
at normalizeArgs (/Users/gendyblackman/Sites/blackmanimages/node_modules/undertaker/lib/helpers/normalizeArgs.js:22:10)
at Gulp.series (/Users/gendyblackman/Sites/blackmanimages/node_modules/undertaker/lib/series.js:13:14)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gendyblackman/Sites/blackmanimages/gulpfile.js:115:9)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
```

Also, when I reinstall Gulp locally I get these errors, shown below.

```
npm ERR! file /Users/gendyblackman/Sites/blackmanimages/package.json

npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json

npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected string in JSON at position 734 while parsing '{

npm ERR! JSON.parse "name": "blackmanimages",

npm ERR! JSON.parse "version'

npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.

npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR! /Users/gendyblackman/.npm/_logs/2018-07-05T14_56_20_043Z-debug.log
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks,

Also, here's my Gulpfile.js

```
// Compiles all SASS files
gulp.task('scss', function () {
      return gulp.src('source/scss/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(scss({
        style: 'compressed',
      }))
    .pipe(rename({
        basename: 'main',
        suffix: '.min',
      }))

    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    });



//Optimizing Images
gulp.task('images', function (){
    return gulp.src('source/img/**/*.+(png|jpg|gif|svg)')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({
      interlaced: true
    })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/img'))
  });

// Uglify js files
 gulp.task('scripts', function () {
    gulp.src('source/js/*.js')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/js'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream());
  });

//Concat and Compress Vendor .js files
 gulp.task('vendors', function () {
          gulp.src(
        [
            'source/js/vendors/jquery.min.js',
            'source/js/vendors/*.js',
        ])
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(concat('vendors.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/assets/js'));
        });

// Watch for changes
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  //Serve files from the root of this project
    browserSync.init({
      server: {
          baseDir: "./build",
            },
      notify: false
      });

  gulp.watch(styleSrc, ['scss']);
  gulp.watch(scriptSrc, ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch(vendorSrc, ['vendors']);
  gulp.watch(['build/*.html', 'build/assets/css/*.css',   'build/assets/js/*.js', 'build/assets/js/vendors/*.js' , '/build/assets/img/*' , '/build/assets/img/'])
.on(' change ', browserSync.reload);

  });

//use default task to launch Browsersync and watch JS files
 gulp.task('default',gulp.series('clean',gulp.parallel('scss', 'scripts', 'vendors',`images`,`fonts`, 'watch'),      function (){
  console.log('Building files');
}));



gulp.task('default', [ 'sass', 'scripts', 'vendors', 'watch'], function () );


gulp.task('default', function (callback) {runSequence(['sass','browserSync', 'watch'],callback)});
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "blackmanimages",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },

    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "^2.24.5",
        "del": "^3.0.0",
        "express": "^4.16.3",
        "gulp": "github:gulpjs/gulp#4.0",
        "gulp-autoprefixer": "^5.0.0",
        "gulp-cache": "^1.0.2",
        "gulp-compass": "^2.1.0",
        "gulp-imagemin": "^4.1.0",
        "gulp-mamp": "0.0.5",
        "gulp-minify-css": "^1.2.4",
        "gulp-plumber": "^1.2.0",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.2.3",
        "gulp-sass": "^4.0.1",
        "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4",
        "minimatch": "^3.0.2",
        "mysql": "^2.15.0",
        "run-sequence": "^2.2.1"
        "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
        "gulp-contrib-copy": "0.1.3",
        "gulp-cssnano": "^2.1.3",
        "gulp-scss": "^1.4.0",
        "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.0",
        "gulp-useref": "^3.1.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: Can you upload `package.json`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've uploaded my package.json

Comment: Do you have `{`  first in `package.json` ?

Comment: Yes I do, It's how the package was created.

Comment: Yes, I edited it.
Do you confirm `Gulpfile.js` is right ?
I see 2 task `scss`  and 3 task `default`.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I think it's right. I was using sass then I change to scss

Comment: What do you mean you see 2 task scss and 3 task default

Comment: But you have 2 task scss, fisrt `task scss 1` same `task sass 2`
And 3 task default .
Your code has 3 task or just has one task (with comment 2 task ) ?

Comment: You has 2 line `gulp.task('scss' ...`

Comment: can you show me these 2 scss and 4 default task

Comment: You can find in your question with `gulp.task('default' ...`

Comment: thats was an uploading error on stack overflow, there should only be one gulp.task('scss' ...

Comment: And 3 task `default`, I think you use one of them and comment 2 task, alright ?

Comment: sorry, you mention "You can find in your question with gulp.task('default' ..." what do you mean?

Comment: In your question, I see you defined 3 task named `default`

Comment: Yes I do have some code comment out

Comment: gulp.task('default', function... and gulp.task('default',...  are both commented out

Comment: Oh, you should update your question

Answer (score 1):

Error:

```
JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON
```

your `package.json` is right format JSON.

Check this line :

```
"run-sequence": "^2.2.1"
```

add `,` to end of this line.

You didn't define task `clean` but you call it:

```
gulp.task('default',gulp.series('clean',gulp.parall .....
```

You should remove it or create `clean`.

You `require('gulp-cache')` but you removed it from `package.json`.

Check enviroment variable `NODE_ENV` is `production` ?
If true, remove it. (because you don't install `devDependencies` if `NODE_ENV` is `production`)

Comment: I make the changes and nothing has changed.

Comment: Same error : `JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript` ?

Comment: I changes package.json to package.JSON and ran my gulpfile in terminal and still got errors.

Comment: But what is that error ? Error `package is not JSON` or another error.

Comment: I get the errors that are listed above "Also, when I reinstall Gulp locally I get these errors, shown below." at the beginning my thread.

Comment: I removed the "gulp.task('default',gulp.series('clean',gulp.parall .....)", I still got the error but it's changed .
[Browserslist] Could not parse /Users/gendyblackman/Sites/blackmanimages/package.json. Ignoring it.
assert.js:269
    throw err;
    ^
This line has changed :AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified

Comment: at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (/Users/gendyblackman/Sites/blackmanimages/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
    
at Gulp.task (/Users/gendyblackman/Sites/blackmanimages/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
    
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/gendyblackman/Sites/blackmanimages/gulpfile.js:123:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)

Comment: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18

Comment: Can you upload your source code ( example `github`).
I going to download it and test. Because you don't update your question, etc.

Comment: Heres that link to my gethub, https://github.com/biblackman/Myfirstsite  for some reason it doesn't have all my files in the source folder.

Comment: For some reason files/folders are missing on GitHub, but I can see them on my GitHub desktop.

Comment: Are you set NODE_ENV is production ?

Comment: Check my pull request

Comment: did it work when you made the changes to the gulp file

Comment: What do you mean, is the "set NODE_ENV is production'?

Comment: if its working for you, then I've got a broke file be it node or gulp.
because I've not gotten a different error:
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:596
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-contrib-copy'

Comment: Do you try add it again ?
Install all module in your package.json

Comment: I've installed all the modules in my package.json. I got this error 
assert.js:269
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
Something must be wrong on my end if it's working for you.

Comment: I got it to work, after it started watching this is what I got, do you get the same thing.
Error: Invalid CSS after "// 2 - HELPERS": expected selector or at-rule, was "@import '2-help..."
        on line 7 of /Users/gendyblackman/Sites/blackmanimages/Myfirstsite/source/scss/main.scss
  Use --trace for backtrace.
[10:04:30] Plumber found unhandled error:
 Error in plugin 'gulp-scss'
Message:
    Compilation failed.: The command exited with code:65

Stack Trace:
undefined